Swift project can't build module from my XCFramework
I need to make a wrapper framework for internal static library(another target in the same project), embedded libabry in framework like this , everything builds fine, but when i try to use created XCFramework , i got these errors:
Failed to build module 'AdvertisementSDK'; this SDK is not supported by the compiler (the SDK is built with 'Apple Swift version 5.8.1 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.5 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)', while this compiler is 'Apple Swift version 5.10 (swiftlang-5.10.0.13 clang-1500.3.9.4)'). Please select a toolchain which matches the SDK.

No such module 'VTVSDKAdPlayer'

Tried to build and archive XCFramework with bash script like this:
# Constants
WORKING_DIRECTORY="VTVSDKAdPlayer"
BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE="release/BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE"

SCHEME="AdvertisementSDK"
DIR_PATH="release/ios/$SCHEME"
DIR_DATA_DIR="$DIR_PATH/DerivedData"

cd $WORKING_DIRECTORY
rm -rf "$BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE"
rm -rf "$DIR_DATA_DIR"

# Build builds for platforms

#iOS
xcodebuild build \
    -project VTVSDKAdPlayer.xcodeproj \
    -derivedDataPath "$DIR_DATA_DIR" \
    -scheme "$SCHEME" \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -configuration Release \
    BUILD_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
    SKIP_INSTALL=NO
    
#Simulator
xcodebuild build \
        -project VTVSDKAdPlayer.xcodeproj \
        -derivedDataPath "$DIR_DATA_DIR" \
        -scheme "$SCHEME" \
        -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" \
        -configuration Release \
        BUILD_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
        SKIP_INSTALL=NO

#TODO - TVos

# Create Folders

FINAL_DIR="$BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE/$SCHEME"

mkdir -p "$FINAL_DIR"

cp -R "$DIR_DATA_DIR/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos" "$FINAL_DIR"
cp -R "$DIR_DATA_DIR/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator" "$FINAL_DIR"


#Create XCFramework

RELEASE_IPHONE_OS="$BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE/$SCHEME/Release-iphoneos"
RELEASE_IPHONE_SIMULATOR="$BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE/$SCHEME/Release-iphonesimulator"
RELEASE_XCFRAMEWORK_OUTPUT="$BUILD_DISTRIBUTIVE/$SCHEME/AdvertisementSDK.xcframework"

find "$FINAL_DIR/" -name "*.swiftinterface" -type f -exec sed -i "" -e "s/@_exported import AdvertisementSDK//g" {} \;

xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
    -framework "$RELEASE_IPHONE_OS/AdvertisementSDK.framework" \
    -framework "$RELEASE_IPHONE_SIMULATOR/AdvertisementSDK.framework" \
    -output "$RELEASE_XCFRAMEWORK_OUTPUT" \


Am I missing something? any suggestions are welcome)
